# Auxiliary input status and Auxiliary input / output supported OBD2 PID

Tags: obd-ii, audio, car

I want to know what does Auxiliary input status (PID 1E) and Auxiliary input / output supported (PID 65) OBD2 PID mean. Do they tell me whether my car is in the Aux mode (while I am listening to the radio)?
Case 1: I am sitting in the car, listening to the radio. Key is in the Aux mode. Will I get any readings on hitting these PIDs?
Case 2: I am driving my car, listening to the radio. Will I get any readings now? Key is not in Aux mode now obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page on [OBD-II PIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs). PID 1E designates if the Power Transfer Output (PTO) is active or not. PID 65 is the sister PID to 1E designating if 1E means anything, supported or not.

A PTO is a device that attaches to an engine/transmission that does other work besides driving the vehicle forward. For example a dump truck commonly had a hydraulic pump that engages with a lever on the transmission to drive the hydraulic ram for the dump bed. Another example is that bucket trucks sometimes called cherry pickers will have a hydraulic pump in the belts of the engine to operate the bucket.

Comment: vini_i Is there any PID/ alternate way to detect if car is in Aux mode. (Not car manufacturer specific)

Comment: @SoumyaSen Not that i'm aware of. Generic OBD was only meant to give emissions and control system related PIDs. These were given for the purposes of diagnosing and repairing vehicles. In this scenario the computer does not need to know the position of the ignition switch.